# E-mail form interactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

I'm a web development student and I need some help. I have the code below; How do I make it work only when the form is submitted and not the text field is clicked. I also would like it to get and insert the textField's value in the .thanks Div. Please help me learn.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".quote").click(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(5000);
    $(".thanks").fadeIn(6000);
    var name = $("#name").val(); 
      $("input").val(text);


  }); 

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.thanks {
    display: none;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="get" id="quote" class="quote">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
<div class="thanks"> $("#name").val();  Thanks for contacting us, we'll get back to you as soon as posible</div><!-- End thanks -->
```

Comment: The code is there now. Dutchie thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit rough and ready but should get you going

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
    //fade out the form - provide callback function so fadein occurs once fadeout has finished
    $("#theForm").fadeOut(500, function () {
        //set the text of the thanks div
        $("#thanks").text("Thanks for contacting us " + $("#name").val());
        //fade in the new div
        $("#thanks").fadeIn(600);
        });

  }); 

});
```

and I changed the html a bit:

```
<div id="theForm">
<form action="" method="get" id="quote" class="quote">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="button" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
</div>
<div id="thanks">Thanks for contacting us, we'll get back to you as soon as posible</div><!-- End thanks -->
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, it worked. I'll also try Nrabinowitz idea also. I'll let others know if it works also.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things at issue here:

By using `$('.quote').click()`, you're setting a handler on *any* click event on any element contained within the `<form>`. If you want to catch only submit events, you should either set a click handler on the submit button:

```
// BTW, don't use an id like "button" - it'll cause confusion sooner or later
$('#button').click(function() { 
    // do stuff
    return false; // this will keep the form from actually submitting to the server,
                  // which would cause a page reload and kill the rest of your JS
});
```

or, preferably, a submit handler on the form:

```
// reference by id - it's faster and won't accidentally find multiple elements
$('#quote').submit(function() { 
    // do stuff
    return false; // as above
});
```

Submit handlers are better because they catch other ways of submitting a form, e.g. hitting `Enter` in a text input.

Also, in your hidden `<div>`, you're putting in Javascript in plain text, not in a `<script>` tag, so that's just going to be visible on the screen. You probably want a placeholder element you can reference:

```
<div class="thanks">Thanks for contacting us <span id="nameholder"></span>, we'll get back to you as soon as possible</div>
```

Then you can stick the name into the placeholder:

```
var name = $("#name").val();
$('#nameholder').html(name);
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with the line `$("input").val(text);` - `text` isn't defined here, so this doesn't really make any sense.